# How can you locate the .po file used for translation of a page?

Tags: translation, language

I'm trying to translate a plugin, Dokan Pro, but I can't seem to find the correct .po file that my Wordpress site is using to translate.

Part of it is already translated in Italian, but other parts are still in English.

I've tried by placing the .po and .mo file for the plugin, named correctly as per [documentation](https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/common-questions/translate-dokan-plugin/) (dokan-it_IT and dokan-lite-it_IT) in the /wp-content/languages/plugins directory, but it won't take that files.

Is there any other .po files from where it could get part of the translation from?

Is it possible that the "part" of the translations are taken from another .po file?

I'd much rather leave the translation files in the recommended folder, and not move them in /wp-content/plugins/dokan/languages

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the .po file I was editing was not the correct one for my plugin. i've reconstructed the .po and .mo with the .pot file inside the plugin, and now translations works just fine.